# Is there a way to change the encoding of the headers in SwiftMailer?

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer

I'm using `SwiftMailer` to send emails but I have some codification problems with `UTF-8` subjects. Swiftmailer uses `QPHeaderEncoder` as default to encode email headers and the safeMap looks like it has some problems with some `UTF-8` French characters. One subject I use contains the word trouvé (found in French) and when the subject gets to the user it shows trouv.

I'd like to use something similar to the `NativeQPContentEncoder` that's available as content encoders but for headers there's only `Base64` and `Quoted Printable` encoders.

Is there a way to fix this, maybe I'm doing something wrong so I paste the code I'm using here

```
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance()

// set encoding in 8 bit
->setEncoder(Swift_Encoding::get8BitEncoding())

// Give the message a subject
->setSubject($subject)

// Set the From address with an associative array
->setFrom(array($from => $niceFrom))

// Set the To addresses with an associative array
->setTo(array($to)) ;
```

Comment: I have Similar problem with pound sign in the message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if in your PHP configuration `mbstring.func_overload` option has any value other than `0`. If yes, change it to `0`, reload your webserver and try to send message again.

`mbstring.func_overload` [overrides](http://php.net/manual/mbstring.overload.php) some string PHP functions and may lead to tricky bugs with UTF-8.

Personally I solved exactly this problem by disabling `mbstring.func_overload`.

Comment: Sorry, it was almost 5 years ago and I'm not sure how I solved that. But I remember that `mbstring.func_overload` was active, so I guess that could be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you know how is your subject string encoded. If it is not UTF-8 then utf8_encode() it.

Also, make sure you setCharset('utf-8') your message.

Comment: I've done that already, all the project strings are UTF-8 and I've checked the charset. Thanks anyway